# Элемент Html просто выходит из родителя

Tags: html, css

В HTML коде написана одна структура а браузер мне сделает совсем другую. Элемент PAY должен находится внутри родителя, а он выходит за рамки

Браузер мне пишет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в коде написано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div id="content">
    <header>
        <h1>Самое популярное</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <a id="container-item">
            <a class="pay">Кнопочка</a>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css код:

```css
#content #container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

#content #container #container-item {
    flex: 250px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 20px;
    transition: .3s all;
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

#content #container #container-item:before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    border: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 10px solid #528ACA;
    border-top: 10px solid #528ACA;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
}

#content #container #container-item:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#content #container .pay {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #528ACA;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: ссылку в ссылку вкладывать без смысленно

Comment: У Вас невалидный код: вкладывать ссылку в ссылку нельзя. Поэтому браузер при построении DOMa сам исправляет эту ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все верно пишут про ссылку внутри ссылки. Тоже самое будет с кнопками внутри ссылки или ссылками внутри кнопок ))

Но по мимо этого, меня как верстальщика с немалым опытом вот такие вещи просто удручают в стилях `#content #container #container-item`

Почему это плохо? Все просто - любой валидатор при попытке вставить в DOM еще один `#container-item` скажет что так нельзя, плюс обратиться к нему например из скрипта будет проблематично. Именно поэтому рекомендуется писать разметку под стилизацию используя не атрибут id, а атрибут class. Что позволяет многократно использовать элементы на странице с одинаковыми стилями.

Answer (score 2):

`<a id="container-item">` сделайте не `<a>` , а `<div>`
у вас два `<a>` один вложен в другой, что нельзя и браузер их делает друг за другом